# using tail in python subprocess takes long time

Tags: python

I am trying to use multiprocessing for my research project. As multiple process will read the same large file in the same time, so I try to make a copy of it within specific range for each process using tail. The specific code is shown as bellow
`python
result = subprocess.call(["tail", "-n", "+" + str(skip+1), resolution_file, ">", skipped_file], shell=True)`

The result is shown as 0, which should have been done. But there is no skipped file I want generated. I also try the code in the python console, but it takes unreasonable long time that i have to keyinterrupt it.

Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Everything but the first argument is ignored here. When you use `shell=True` with a list, the *very first list element* is the only thing parsed as a shell script. Subsequent list elements are `$0`, `$1`, etc. in the context where that script is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code hangs because it's waiting for an EOF on stdin, not reading `resolution_file` at all.

Taking out `shell=True` fixes this:

```
result = subprocess.call(["tail", "-n", "+" + str(skip+1), resolution_file],
                         stdout=open(skipped_file, 'w'))
```

---

...now, **why** did it behave that way? Because `shell=True` prepends `['sh', '-c']` to your argument list. Thus, your original code was actually doing the following:

```
result = subprocess.call(["sh", "-c", "tail", "-n", "+" + str(skip+1), resolution_file, ">", skipped_file])
```

And what does **that** do? Well, it runs `sh -c 'tail'`, with subsequent arguments available to the shell script `tail`. Except that script *doesn't look at its other arguments at all*, so they're just ignored. And when it's passed no arguments, `tail` just waits for an EOF on stdin... one which, in the case at hand, never comes.

---

So, what if you **did** want to use `shell=True`, and to open the output file from inside the shell rather than from your Python code? In that case, you might write the code as such:

```
result = subprocess.call([
  'tail -n +"$1" -- "$2" >"$3"', '_',   # script itself, then $0 it's run with
  str(skip+1),                          # this is $1 for the script
  resolution_file,                      # ...its $2...
  skipped_file                          # ...and its $3
], shell=True)
```